# Minimal polynomial of an operator T and its complexification are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

The definition of the complexification of a vector space V is in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). The complexification $T^c$ of a linear transformation $T$ is defined by $T^c(u+iv)=T(u)+iT(v)$. Now, consider the minimal polynomial $m_{T}$ of $T$. We have  $m_{T}(T^c)=(m_{T}(T))^c=0$. Hence, $m_{T^{c}}\left ( x \right )|m_{T}\left ( x \right )$, but how to prove the other direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $B = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ a basis of $V$ and $B' = \{v_1 +i0, \ldots, v_n + i0\}$ a basis of $V^c$.

Then $[T^c]_{B'} = [T]_B \in M_n(\Bbb R) \subset M_n(\Bbb C)$.

Since $m_{T^c}$ is the minimal polynomial of this matrix, the question boils down to chekcing that the minimal polynomial of matrix of real numbers is the same as the minimal polynomial of the matrix viewed as one with complex entries.

This is always the case: fix $A$ a matrix with real entries and $p \in \mathbb{C}[X] \setminus \mathbb{R}[X]$ monic. If $p(A)$, then $0 = \overline{p(A)} = \overline{p}(A)$. By hypothesis we also know that $q = p-\overline{p}$ is nonzero, $\deg q < \deg p$ and $q(A) = 0$. In particular $p \neq m_A$.

**Edit:** the argument above is also considered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158165/minimal-polynomial-over-the-complex-field).

I think it can be generalized in the case of $F/k$ a Galois extension (perhaps this is stronger than needed) as follows: consider $A \in M_n(F)$ and $m_A \in F[X]$ its minimal polynomial. Fix $\sigma \in \mathbf{Gal}(F/k)$ and write $(-)^\sigma$ for the endomorpshism rings of $F[X], M_n(F)$ given by applying $\sigma$ coefficient/entry-wise.

If $A \in M_k(k)$, then $A^\sigma = A$. Hence $(m_A)^\sigma (A) = (m_A)^\sigma(A^\sigma) = (m_A(A))^\sigma = 0$. In particular, the polynomial $q = m_A - m_A^\sigma$ has degree less than $m_A$ and satisfies $q(A) = 0$. By degree considerations, it must be $q = 0$. But then each coefficient $a$ of $m_A$ satisfies $\sigma(a) = a$. In other words, the coefficients of $m_A$ lie in $F^{\mathbf{Gal}(F/k)} = k$, as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Any (real) basis of the real vector space $V$ gives rise to a (complex) basis of it complexification $\def\C{{\Bbb C}}V^\C$ (you already use the embedding $V\hookrightarrow V^\C$ when writing $u+\mathbf{i}v\in V^\C$) and the matrix of $T^\C$ with respect to the latter basis is just the same as the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to the former basis. The minimal polynomial $\mu_T$ of $T$ is the same as that of the real matrix$~A$, so your question amounts to showing that, even allowing complex coefficients, this is still the minimal polynomial of $A$ viewed as complex matrix. But the powers of $A$ with exponents less than the degree of $\mu_T$ are linearly independent as real matrices, and therefore also as complex matrices, which shows this.